# Set an offset value for each cell in a range VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to compare a value to each cell in a range. Once there is a match, I want to set another variable to old the value that is offset 3 columns over.

```
For Each i In Worksheets("SFDC Input").Range("D2:D20").Cells
    If ProductFamily = i Then
        i.Offset(0, -3).Value = ID
    End If
Next
```

ProductFamily is the value I am comparing to i. I want ID to be the value holder.

Comment: is `ID` not being set as the value? Is that what you're asking?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks as though your assignment (`=`) is backwards. You're setting `i.Offset(0, -3).Value` to `ID` instead of setting `ID` to the value.

Try the following:

```
ID = i.Offset(0, -3).Value
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/41d8z008.aspx):

> The = operator assigns the value on its right to the variable or
>   property on its left.